# Bootstrap Varying modal content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bunch of content that all trigger the same modal, however, the content is slightly different for each, I've managed to change the title and description following bootstraps guide but can't seem to update the icon. Alternatively, is there a way to target the h3 and P tag within the link to pull the information through or is adding data attributes to each link the best method? (Sorry my JS knowledge is not great)

**Link**

```
<a data-desc="this is a test" data-image="/build/images/app-icons/slack.svg" data-title="Slack 3" data-target="#appListModal" data-toggle="modal" href="">
<div class="media">
<img alt="Generic placeholder image" class="mr-3 app-icon" id="a-icon" src="/build/images/app-icons/slack.svg">
<div class="media-body">
  <h3 class="mt-0" id="app-title">Slack</h3>
  <p>Team and client communication</p>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

**Modal Body**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img class="modal-icon" id="app-icon" src="/build/images/app-icons/slack.svg">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Slack</h3>
    <p class="modal-desc">Team and client communication</p><button class="btn" type="button"><span class="align-middle"><img class="tag-icon" src="/build/images/app-icons/link.svg">Visit website</span></button> <button class="btn" type="button"><span class="align-middle"><img class="tag-icon" src="/build/images/app-icons/play.svg">View Tutorial</span></button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#appListModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var apptitle = button.data('title')
var appdesc = button.data('desc')
var image = button.data('image')

// Extract info from data-* attributes
// If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
// Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
var modal = $(this)
modal.find('.modal-title').text(apptitle)
modal.find('.modal-desc').text(appdesc)
modal.find('.modal-icon').src = (image)   })
```

Comment: can you try not passing in the image but using a switch case on the title inside of the js to decide which image to use?

Comment: @adina could you please give an example?

Comment: what is `modal-icon` ? is it a class or id ? i'm guessing this selector is the issue

Comment: its a class I just changed it to .modal-icon but still doesn't pull it through..

Comment: @dizzieRhys yes: switch (apptitle) case 'Slack 3': image = ... and so on

Comment: Also, you can find a way to get to the button that was clicked by using $(this) so maybe you can use jquery to get the image element after it

Comment: @adina I'll have to see if I can find some videos as I have no idea how that works :/

Comment: @dizzieRhys https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp